# Polymorphic Route Model Binding in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

is there any way of creating a Polymorphic-like model implicitly binding on laravel 5.* ??

for example:

`route('project.comment.store', $project->commentable)`

register the route like this

`Route::get('comments/{commentable}/store', ....controller . '@store')`

and receive the exactly model on the controller store() method?

im guessing the only way i could archive this is if i modify the route to something like this

`Route::get('comments/{commentable_type}/{commentable_id}/store', ....controller . '@store')`

which looks a big ugly.. but works... any idea if is there any short and smarter way of doing so?

Comment: Why don't you send the id of the object via POST to the method and then use Comments::find($id) to get the object?

Comment: there is a problem on this in my code...if i do send the id of $project->id instead of the $project->commentable->id and it would work when i retrieve the $project->find($id)->commentable->comments->create()..... the problem is the $project->commentable may change to a instance of another commentable object from time to time.. so the object that ->commentable refers now might not be the same object when it reaches the controller on the post method

Comment: What did you end up doing Rafael?

Comment: that's a really hard question.... i did manage to get this working but i don't have any memory more of the project i was in need of this...

Comment: Related: [[5.6] Allow nullable method injection (Polymorphic Route Model Binding) by mpyw · Pull Request #22488 · laravel/framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/22488)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm late.  You can polymorphic route model bind like this:

1. Add a Route::bind() to either the RouteServiceProvider or your packages ServiceProvider.  Your custom model resolution logic will go there.
2. Inject a plain old \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model rather than anything specific.  (Or whatever base model you extend from).

Here's an example from my existing code...  My binding is on /my-model/{key}/seo.  During the bind, I custom resolve MyModel from my-model and then use {key} for the id.

// my package routes file

```
Route::group(['as' => 'fuqu::', 'namespace' => 'FuquIo\\LaravelTags', 'middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function (){

$models = config(\FuquIo\LaravelTags\ServiceProvider::SHORT_NAME .'.orm');

foreach($models as $short_name => $fqns_class){
    $kebbab_name= kebab_case($short_name);

    Route::get("/$kebbab_name/{key}/seo", [
        'as'   => "$kebbab_name.seo",
        'uses' => function(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $model){
        return $model;
    }
    ]);
}

});
```

// my package ServiceProvider.php (or your RouteServiceProvider.php) in the boot() but you need to `use Illuminate\Routing\Route as RouteInfo;` for that injection I'm doing in the bind.

```
// at the top
use Illuminate\Routing\Route as RouteInfo;
...
// then inject RouteInfo for your binding logic so you can tear apart your url/uri.
Route::bind('key', function ($key, RouteInfo $route) {
        $info = explode('/{key}', $route->uri());
        $kebab = $info[0];
        $orm = studly_case($kebab);
        $fqns_class = config(self::SHORT_NAME .'.orm.'. $orm);
        return $fqns_class::findOrFail($key);
    });
```

So, in my case I've got a config file mapping SimpleNames => Fully\NameSpaced\Names::class, but you don't need that.  You can resolve however you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this

```
Route::apiResource('projects.comments', [CommentController::class, 'index'])
    ->parameters([
        'projects' => 'commentable',
    ]);
```

...and then in controller (without type hint)

```
public function index($commentable)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem that is pretty clean. It only requires that you use morph maps and that the route has the same name(or pluralized) as the morph entry.

### Route

```php
Route::apiResource('customers.addresses', AddressController::class)
    ->parameter('customers','morphParent')
    ->scoped();
```

### Service Provider

```php
Route::bind('morphParent', function($value, RoutingRoute $route) {
    $name = str($route->action['as'])->before('.')->singular()->toString();
    $model = Relation::getMorphedModel($name);

    return $model::findOrFail($value);
});
```

### Controller

```php
public function store(Model $addressable, AddressRequest $request): JsonResource
{
    ...
}
```

You could make morphGrandParent binding etc too.